# Adding mysql data with php into an accordion

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

[code]

```
<?php
mysql_connect("","","") or die("Could not connect to localhost");
mysql_select_db("") or die( "Could not connect to database");

$names[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY name ASC");

// The list wasn't sorted, if you don't want sorting you can just remove this line.
asort($names);

// Prepare list for accordion.
$accordionData = [];
foreach($names as $name) {
  $accordionData[substr($name, 0, 1)][] = $name;
}

?>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active: false
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
<?php
// Print accordion, change the echoes to reflect your accordion html.
foreach($accordionData as $index => $names) {
?>

  <h3><?php echo strtoupper($index); ?></h3>
  <div>
  <?php
  foreach($names as $name) {
  ?>
    <p><?php echo ucfirst($name); ?></p>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
</div>
```

I get two errors:

> Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 14
>
> Warning: ucfirst() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 49

If I put the names out of array how would I get the names into the accordion?

Comment: you can continue the discussion over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126829/adding-mysql-data-with-php-into-an-accordion

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_*` functions to handle the resources returned by mysql_query.

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY name ASC");

while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
  echo $data['name']; // contains list.name from your db
```

Besides, you'd prefer using `PDO` as mysql_* is deprecated since 5.3. Look about it [there](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @ Thomas and how would I use that to add the content into the accordian by letters

Comment: @ Thomas : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 34

Comment: @ThomasRuiz although I agree that you shouldn't do his homework. You can be more helpful by pointing him to the right place instead of just saying "Use your brain":

MethodManX Here's PDO PHP page, there are plenty of examples for you to read, and if you get stuck feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: line 34: foreach($data as $index => $names)

Comment: @ Thomas can you please help me with that one line. That's all I ask.

Comment: @MethodManX read the doc about how to use it on php.net. There are examples, explanations and everything you need on this page : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` function runs an SQL statement and (if this is a `SELECT` statement) returns a result. You have to process this result with a suitable function like `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY name ASC");

$names = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

then use the `$names` array with field keys in a loop (`while`). For example, `$names["name"]` gets the name field value of the current row.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <?php
        // Print accordion, change the echoes to reflect your accordion html.
        while($names = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<h3>" . substr(strtoupper($names["name"]),0,1) . "</h3>";
            //first letter of the name
            echo "<div>";

            foreach($names as $name) 
            {
                echo  "<p>" . ucfirst($name) . "</p>";
            }
            echo "</div>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Yes, we know `mysql_*` is deprecated.